# Как добавить новое поле в модель django?

Tags: python, django

Создаю новое приложение Django. Так сказать тренируюсь.
Описал модель Competition

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Проделал миграцию и всё такое.
Потом понял что в модель надо добавить ещё одно поле.

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    event_place = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Создаю миграцию - `python manage.py makemigrations`
Провожу миграцию - `python manage.py migrate`
Но в таблице новое поле не не создаётся.
[image: Таблица]
Как всё таки добавить новое поле в базу? База данных - SQLite. Django 2.0

Содержание файла migrations

```
# Generated by Django 2.0 on 2017-12-15 06:15

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('competitions', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Competition',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)),
                ('event_place', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ],
    ]
```

Вывод `python manage.py showmigrations`

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
competitions
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20171215_0915
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
home
 (no migrations)
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: После выполнения `makemigrations` файл миграции появился? Он содержит необходимое поле? Какие-либо ошибки возникли в процессе выполнения `migrate`? Что показывает `showmigrations`?

Comment: Старые миграции не удаляли?

Comment: Добавил вывод showmigrations

Comment: Покажите миграцию `0001_initial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил таким способом:
Удалил все файлы, кроме `__init__.py`, из папок `migrations` и файл `db.sqlite3` с базой.
Потом снова создал начальную миграцию
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`
И суперпользователя
`python manage.py createsuperuser`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поставить default равное пустой строке:

```
   event_place = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

Затем следует заново провести миграцию.